# Delphi CompilerVersion directive issues

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-5, compiler-directives

I have a library code file which is shared between Delphi 5 and DelphiXE2. I am attempting to add anonymous method functionality to the code file, but only for DelphiXE2 projects (since Delphi 5 doesn't support anonymous methods). It seemed I should be able to use the CompilerVersion (Note: I don't want to limit it to DelphiXE2, just in case we ever upgrade).

```
{$IF CompilerVersion >= 23}
  {$DEFINE AnonymousAvail}
{$IFEND}
```

This worked nicely in XE2, but it turns out, Delphi 5 doesn't support the $IF directive. I decided to wrap it in an $IFDEF. This worked nicely in Delphi 5, but XE2 also doesn't seem to have CompilerVersion defined, so AnonymousAvail is not defined.

```
{$IFDEF CompilerVersion}
  {$IF CompilerVersion >= 23}
    {$DEFINE AnonymousAvail}
  {$IFEND}
{$ENDIF}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Note: I cannot move anonymous method code to a different code file.

Comment: If you remove the {$IFDEF CompilerVersion} block, does it work for Delphi 5?

Comment: No that doesn't work in Delphi 5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do what the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Conditional_compilation_%28Delphi%29#Using_Conditional_Defines_for_the_Compiler_Version) says:

```
{$IFDEF ConditionalExpressions}
  {$IF CompilerVersion >= 23.0}
    {$DEFINE AnonymousAvailable}
  {$IFEND}
{$ENDIF}
```

Be sure that the outer condition is as shown (and closed with ENDIF) and you can use CompilerVersion and other constants and expressions inside.

You can also use

```
{$IF defined(BLAH)}
```

or, one of my favourites:

```
{$IF declared(AnsiString)}
```

etc...

---

FWIW, I noticed that the example in the link comes, almost verbatim, from my [Console.pas](http://www.rvelthuis.de/programs/console.html) unit.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz yes, I misread that second paragraph. So essentially I was checking if a constant was defined when I needed to check one of the predefined conditionals.

Comment: You can check if a constant is defined, and even query its value. CompilerVersion is a normal Pascal constant, it is not a predefined conditional.